# A classic fiction about a mysterious thunder that comes from the Carolina mountains

Tags: identification-request

A long time I started a story but never finished it. Now I cannot find it because I forgot the author and title. I remember it being from a famous author but not his most famous work.

The story starts with a reporter hired to research terrible sounds coming from western Carolina mountains (Asheville). It turns out that something has opened up in the earth (like a volcano) and shot out a supersonic "vehicle" that is tearing across the nation. Citizens and news media are terrified of this new menace to the civilized world and cannot capture it.

That is as far as I got. I would love to pick up from there and find out what happens. Does this sound familiar to anybody?

Comment: Welcome to Lit.SE! Are there any other details you might remember like approximate publican date (or at least when you read it), was there any distinctive cover art, was it a short story or novel, etc.  [See here for some guidelines](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/778/guidelines-for-good-story-id-questions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like Jules Verne's [*Master of the World*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_of_the_World_(novel)). There is an [on-line copy](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/3809) so you can easily check.

Comment: TY! That's it. Jules Verne's less famous story. Please don't tell me how it ends.

Comment: I think Verne had MANY less famous stories.  They are all fun, in a self-indulgent kind of way.

Comment: I wonder if there was ever a radio production of Master of the World? Like Orson Welles.